# Convertir ASCII en hexadecimal

Tags: python

Tengo una string  y la quiero convertir en hexadecimal y realizar un checksum con el resultado obtenido.

```
s = "01STS"
a = s.encode("utf-8").hex()
print (a)
```

Resultado:

```
3031535453
```

La conversión es correcta, pero quiero sumar los valores del resultado y obtener el checksum con el valor `5B`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener el checksum debes sumar los bytes de tu mensaje, quedándote con el resto de la división entre 256.

Esto puedes hacerlo antes de haber pasado todos tus bytes a hexadecimal:

```
s = "01STS"

b = s.encode("utf8")
checksum = sum(b)%256
a = b.hex()
```

Ahora, si quieres ver el checksum en hexadecimal también, puedes usar una cadena de formato apropiado:

```
print(a)
print("{:X}".format(checksum))
```

Resultado:

```
3031535453
5B
```

### Otra forma

También puedes hacerlo después de haber pasado los bytes a hexadecimal, es decir, cuando todo lo que tienes es ya la cadena `"3031535453"`. Esto es más complejo e innecesario en este caso, pero por si te interesa...

Para ello hay que dividir esa cadena de 2 en 2 caracteres para obtener "30", "31", "53", etc.. pasar cada uno de estos elementos a entero (teniendo en cuenta que están en base 16) y luego ya, como antes, sumarlos todos y quedarse con el módulo 256.

La forma más simple de dividir la cadena de 2 en 2 en una sola línea puede ser hacer uso de `re.findall()` así:

```
import re

a = "3031535453"
checksum = sum(int(byte, 16) for byte in re.findall("..", a))%256
```

Sale el mismo valor de antes, 91 (5B en hexadecimal)

Comment: reutilizando el código, es posible invertir los bits? para obtener tanto 5B como A4?

Comment: Imagino que te refieres al complemento a 1 (cambiar 1 por 0 y viceversa). En ese caso, una vez tienes el checksum normal, el complemento a 1 sería `(255-checksum)`, o también `255^checksum` (operación XOR)